# edit invoice template in module prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm using press the shop version 1.7. I'm about to make a small module/add on, that will give border in product quantity cell in invoice if quantity is greater than 1. What are the possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Hook actionPDFInvoiceRender to intercept template values and add a PDF override in your module to manage rendering.